Implicitly has any type because expression of type string can't be used to index type unknown error on a Type T[] List when using forEach
I am trying to create a React Component that iterates over a list of generic objects, Type <T>, which was defined using the following Interface, and then generated using the applyFilters method:
export interface FilterCriteria<T> {
    key: keyof T;
    method: (item: T, searchTerm: string) => boolean;
}

// Etc...

    applyFilters = () => {
        const { searchTerm, selectedFilters } = this.state;
        const { initialData, onFilter, filterCriteria } = this.props;

        let filteredData = initialData.filter(item =>
            filterCriteria.some(criteria => criteria.method(item, searchTerm))
        );

        console.log("Dados após aplicar todos os filtros:", filteredData);

        // Aplicando o resultado final dos filtros.
        onFilter(filteredData);
    };

The filteredData list of type T[] is created and filtered successfully, as it shows perfectly on the console.log I did right after. So, now is where the problem happens:
I added a iteration over this list, using another Interface of type <T>, like this:
// First, I defined the Interface that contains the selected options.
export interface FilterOptions<T> {
    initialDataKey: keyof T;
    optionLabel: string;
    optionsList: FilterSelectableOption[];
}

interface FilterSelectableOption {
    valueForFilter: string;
    valueLabel: string;
}

// Then, I applied the Interface and filters on my `filteredData` created in the first code.
    applyFilters = () => {
        const { searchTerm, selectedFilters } = this.state;
        const { initialData, onFilter, filterCriteria } = this.props;

        let filteredData = initialData.filter(item =>
            filterCriteria.some(criteria => criteria.method(item, searchTerm))
        );

        // Added logic for applying filters from the dropdowns.
        Object.entries(selectedFilters).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (value !== "Todos") {
                filteredData = filteredData.filter(item => {
                    return String(item[key]).toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase();
                });
            }
        });

        console.log("Dados após aplicar todos os filtros:", filteredData);

        // Aplicando o resultado final dos filtros.
        onFilter(filteredData);
    };

Since this is a list of type T[], I expected that I would be able to iterate over this list, using forEach, and when accessing Item that has a type T I would be able to access its index directly, like in the code above.
Instead, I am receiving the error TS7053: Element implicitly has any type because expression of type string can't be used to index type unknown. No index signature with a parameter of type string was found on type unknown
What am I doing wrong?
